# Show 2 plots at the same time

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.10, graphing

I have this code to generate the partial sums of pi (this is the part which graphs it):

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(piresults)
plt.ylabel('value of calculated pi')
plt.xlabel('number of fractions calculated')
piresults2=[]
for result in piresults:
  piresults2.append(math.fabs((result-math.pi)/math.pi))
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(piresults2)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.ylabel('error %')
plt.xlabel('number of fractions calculated')
plt.show()
```

But my problem is the plots dont appear at the same time

I was expecting the two plots to appear alongside each other after only using plt.show() at the end and making the figures separate. But that's not happening? They appeared separately and i had to close one to get the other

Comment: Look up `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're popping up as separate windows, you could draw two plots on a single figure/window instead.

Use `plt.subplots()` to create a figure that has multiple subplots (`axes`). Select each subplot in turn (`axes[0]`, then `axes[1]`) to plot on.

[image]

```py
piresults1 = np.linspace(3.12, 3.16)
piresults2 = np.linspace(0.2, 0.6)

#Create figure with 2 subplots ("axes")
figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 3))

#Get the handle of the first subplot, axes[0], and plot
ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(piresults1)
ax.set_ylabel('value of calculated pi')
ax.set_xlabel('number of fractions calculated')

#Get the handle of the second subplot, axes[1], and plot
ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(piresults2)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set_ylabel('error %')
ax.set_xlabel('number of fractions calculated')
```